# Transfer Users groups in AD with an audit trail

Tags: powershell, active-directory, active-directory-group

I need to copy a users groups to anothers and have an audit trail.

this is the code I have:

```
#This is the user name of the account you want to copy.  
$old = Read-Host

#This is the user account you want to copy to. 
$new = Read-Host

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $old | Set-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $new |
  Export-Csv "pathhere" -NoTypeInformation
```

This is essentially the code I thought might work

```
#This is the user name of the account you want to copy.  
$old = Read-Host

#This is the user account you want to copy to. 
$new = Read-Host

Get-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $uold | Set-ADPrincipalGroupMembership $new |
  Export-Csv "pathhere" -NoTypeInformation
```

I have no idea what I need to do to complete this what should be simple command in PowerShell.

Comment: Principal Group Membership is not all groups. It is your primary group (think Domain Users). `Get-AdGroupMember` would get all the other groups.

Comment: "code you have" and "code you think might work" are essentially the same, so why post it twice? Also, you need to explain what doesn't work as expected. Matt pointed out one thing, but there might be more depending on what you actually want to achieve in the end.